# Vuex computed property not updating v-show

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a simple Vuex module with one object: selectedEvent.

I am able to update my selected event using:

```
  <Event :event="selectedEvent" />
```

However, I am unable to update the visibility of this property using a computed getter defined in the module:

```
  <Event :event="selectedEvent" v-show="isEventSelected" />
```

My computed values in App.js:

```
  computed: mapState({
    selectedEvent: state => state.events.selectedEvent,
    isEventSelected: state => state.events.isEventSelected
  })
```

I'm aware that Vue has trouble observing some Object/ Array changes, so I have used `Vue.set` in my mutation. I have also attempted to move v-show inside the Event component, with no success.

If I move the getter logic inside the v-show, it works fine (however it's messy), e.g.:

`<Event :event="selectedEvent" v-show="selectedEvent.hasOwnProperty('id')" />`

I'm fairly new to Vue - What am I missing here?

**store/modules/events.js:**

```
import { EVENT_SELECT } from "./types";
import Vue from "vue";

const state = {
  selectedEvent: {}
};

const getters = {
  selectedEvent: state => {
    return state.selectedEvent;
  },
  isEventSelected: state => {
    return state.selectedEvent.hasOwnProperty("id");
  }
};

const actions = {
  setSelectedEvent({ commit }, selectedEvent) {
    commit(EVENT_SELECT, selectedEvent);
  }
};

const mutations = {
  [EVENT_SELECT](state, selectedEvent) {
    Vue.set(state, "selectedEvent", selectedEvent);
  }
};

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
};
```

**App.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <b-container>
      <Calendar />
      <Event :event="selectedEvent" v-show="selectedEvent.hasOwnProperty('id')"/>
    </b-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Calendar from "./components/Calendar.vue";
import Event from "./components/Event.vue";
import { mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    Calendar,
    Event
  },
  computed: mapState({
    selectedEvent: state => state.events.selectedEvent,
    isEventSelected: state => state.events.isEventSelected
  })
};
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you have a _getter_ named `selectedEvent` that just returns `state.selectedEvent`?

Comment: @Phil I was using it as shorthand to reference the state object. Not sure if that's a good idea or not, I preferred it to writing <Event :event="this.$store.state.events.selectedEvent" />

Comment: Using the `computed` properties is fine in your component, what I mean is in your store you have a `state` property `selectedEvent` **and** a getter also named `selectedEvent` that doesn't do anything other than return the state property. The getter is completely redundant

Comment: @Phil you're right - It was completely unnecessary. I thought the mapState was using my getter for some reason ... Now realize it just references the state directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your store, `isEventSelected` is a *getter*, not a state property so you should use [`mapGetters`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper), eg

```js
import { mapState, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

// snip

computed: {
  ...mapState('events', ['selectedEvent']),
  ...mapGetters('events', ['isEventSelected'])
}
```